# Probability that an integral of brownian motion is greater than $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

> Compute the probability $\mathbb{P}\big(\int_0^1 W(t) dt > \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \big)$

Clearly, as I am not sure about where to start I am confused about how the $W(t)$ relates to an integral and how this number could relate to a probability.

1) Should I evaluate the integral first? Not sure how to do this.

2) Should I square both sides (risky)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First noticed that $\int_{0}^{t}{W_sds}$ is Gaussian : $W$ is continuous, and can be written as the limit of a Riemann sum of Brownian increments.

$$\int_{0}^{t}{W_sds}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{W_{\frac{(k-1)t}{n}}\left(\frac{kt}{n}-\frac{(k-1)t}{n}\right)}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(W_{\frac{kt}{n}}-W_{\frac{(k-1)t}{n}}\right)\left(t-\frac{kt}{n}\right)}$$

The mean of the integral is $0$ and the variance is $\frac{t^3}{3}$.

Introduce the standard normal variable $Y$, and we have 
$$\int_{0}^{1}{W_sds}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}Y$$

Therefore,
$$P\left(\int_{0}^{1}{W_sds} >\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=P\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}Y>\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=P\left(Y>2\right)=1-P(Y \leq2)=1-\Phi(2)=\Phi(-2)$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of $Y$.

Comment: how did you get variance is $\frac{t^3}{3}$?

Comment: I answered that question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488424/partition-of-brownian-motion/3488447#3488447